# Did 4 other angles that equal x

Tags: geometry, circles

O is the center.
MR is a tangent.

I used a tangent chord for one of the reasons, but cannot seem to find other angles that equal ‘x’. Thank you.
Please note that this is a 11th grade question.

[image: circle geometry]

Comment: What are you supposed to show? Do you just want to find other angles that are equal to $\angle NRM$? If so, have you applied the [alternate segment theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/alternate-segment-theorem-2/)?

Comment: Find angles that equal angle R3 . I have used angles in the same segment but what angle equals it for example is it T2?

Comment: What have you tried? There's one (unlabelled) angle that follows from alternate segment theorem, which leads to another angle. Can you find either of them?

Comment: I have use N2 reason tan chord. Does that then lead to O2 angles in the same segment?

Comment: What is N2 equal to? How did you get it from tangent chord theorem? Which tangent are you using?

Comment: N2 would be equal to R3 which is x ad I used MR as a tangent.

Comment: Can you elaborate fully? What are the steps if MR is the tangent? What is the chord? Note that $T$ can be any points along $RM$, so it would be very strange for $RNT$ to be always equal to a fixed value.

Comment: Listen my guy. The tangent chord theorem gives us $ \angle TRN = \angle RPN$. it does not give us $ \angle TRN = \angle RNT$. This was why I was trying to get you to show your work, to try and identify where you made a mistake. I hope this was helpful. I'm exiting this conversation.